# Output to a file in java

Tags: java

How do I specify the path where I want to save my file when creating an output to a file in java?

```
//Set up Printer Output file
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter (new BufferedWriter (new FileWriter("project61.dat")));
```

For some  reason after running my program, I don't see that my project61.dat file is created. I can't find anywhere in my C drive.

Comment: Why can't you open up the documentation?

Answer (score 1):

Simple google search yields helpful examples. 
Here is one taken from [here](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0180__File/UsingPrintWriter.htm):

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

public class MainClass {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
       PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter("c:\\temp\\printWriterOutput.txt");
       pw.println("PrintWriter is easy to use.");
       pw.println(1234);
       pw.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {}
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use the following

```
//Set up Printer Output file
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter (new BufferedWriter (new FileWriter("project61.dat")));
```

Then it will create the file under your project. Please find the file where you project available.

If you want to write this file in a particular directory then mention the absolute path.

```
   PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter (new BufferedWriter (new FileWriter("c:\\project61.dat")));
   pw.write("Test");
   pw.close();
```

It will create the file under "C:" directory.

If you use the absolute directory `"C://temp//project61.dat"` then the temp folder must be available in c drive. The folder will not be created by default.